# Most efficient way to store real time sentiment data

Tags: database, performance, database-design, nosql, sentiment-analysis

I am planning on creating an app to store twitter sentiment in a database for specific topics.  I don't need to store the tweets, just the sentiment of the topic.  I can use either a SQL or noSQL DB.  The app will be ingesting a lot of data, so it needs to be efficient.

I'm wondering if it's more efficient to ingest the tweeets, store them in a noSQL DB, then as a separate process, read the tweats from the DB and analyze the sentiment and store it.  Or, is it more efficient to read the tweets individually from the API, determine sentiment on the fly, and store the sentiment in the DB?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the better solution is analyzing the tweets as they come in and using your logic to create the sentiment and store in your choice of DB. Storing all the incoming tweets before analysis could create an unnecessary bottle neck in your application. In addition, you don't really need to store all that raw data.